# Find the sum of two numbers which are in the separate line?

Tags: c

So there is a problem on [SPOJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPOJ) as mentioned below:

> Given two natural numbers (both not greater than 200), each number in the separate line, please print the sum of them.
>
> > Example Input:
> >
> > 2
> >
> > 3
> >     
> >     Output: 5

So I wrote a program to this problem. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int input1, input2, sum;
    printf("Enter two natural numbers\n");
    scanf("%d", &input1);
    scanf("\n%d", &input2);
    if ((input1>0&&input1<=200) && (input2>0&&input2<=200))
    {
        sum = input1 + input2;
        printf("%d", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But SPOJ rejected this answer as a wrong answer.

Later I checked this on [idone](https://ideone.com/P6rBhE).

But I'm unable to detect, what's wrong with this answer, as expected it gives the same output given in above question.
Please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: And delete this line `printf("enter two natural numbers\n");`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thnxs, its accepted now.

Comment: It wants a newline after the sum, probably: `printf("%d\n", sum);`.  Maybe you should check the return values from `scanf()` to ensure values were read.  Maybe you shouldn't prompt for the inputs, either — that becomes part of the output and likely isn't what they're looking for.

Comment: `if((input1>0&&input1<=200) && (input2>0&&input2<=200) )` isn't needed as the problem statement already guarantees it.

Comment: why downvoted ? please mention!!

Comment: @mssirvi probably because no aparent debugging done.

Answer (score 1):

The first print statement

```
printf("enter two natural numbers\n");
```

The Second

```
scanf("%d",&input1);//Press Enter
```

The Third

```
scanf("%d",&input2);//Press Enter
```

And finally

```
printf("\n%d",sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the printf statement as it is not needed and will mess up the expected I/O as given by SPOJ.

Next, there is no need of the newline character in `scanf`. You can directly write `scanf("%d %d", &input1, &input2);`. Another way would be to write the `scanf` statement twice as:

```
scanf("%d", &input1);
scanf("%d", &input2);
```

Lastly, you can also remove the `if` statement, if input bounds are given by SPOJ.